# how to handle multiple error in express api?like i want to handle 404,405,400 and 500

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

as i'm new to node.js and i have using express framework to build rest api.
i want to handle multiple error for my api.like i want to handle 404,405,400 and 500.
express is giving default error handler.but i don't understand how that works.so i want to build custom middleware to handle all that error.

**catch 404 and forwarding to error handler**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) 
{
    var err = new Error('URL Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Bad Request');
    err.status = 400;
    next(err);
});
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.json({
            err:{

                message:err.message,
                statuscode:err.status
            }
        })
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

**production error handler no stacktraces leaked to user**

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
```

i have handled 404,400 and 500.but i am not able to handler 405 error.either i can handle 404 or 405.both are not working together

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using express and router property:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());



mongoose
.connect(db, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected..."))
.catch(err => console.log(err));


router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const { data} = req.body; // This gets the data from the body of the request, using body-parser
  if (!data) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "Data should not be empty!" });
  }
});

app.use("/")
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

by the help of this statement in the router function, you can pass the error status with a json to the front-end:

```
return res.status(400).json({ error: "Data should not be empty!" });
```

check it: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status

using an error-handling middleware, for example, create a error.js file:

```
const app = require('express');

const error = app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
   if (user == null || user == 'undefined') {
   res.status(404);
    }
   next();
})

module.exports = error;
```

You can now use it in the router function like:

```
const error = require("../middleware/error");

router.post("/", error, (req, res) => {
  const { data} = req.body; //now beacuse of the "error" in the parameters, if the request pass the error, than it will continue to this function

});
```

Comment: yes.i can do that.but i wan to handle all my errors in my app.js file.as you have suggested,i have to handle error in all my routes .so i want to build middleware that can handle all my errors.